# emacs space regex search

Tags: regex, search, emacs

I want to search for x spaces at the start of a line, using interactive regular search `^SPC<` selects all lines starting with a variable number of spaces. According to emacs wiki

```
 (setq search-whitespace-regexp " ")
```

Should solve this, but this reverses behavior: it selects one space when i'm entering multiple spaces in my search. I do not remember this behavior from earlier emacs (using 23.2 now). Is there a way to make interactive search select one space when entered one space and x spaces when entered x spaces?

cheers
Jeroen

Comment: I just ran across this (in emacs 24). I'm so glad it's easy to disable. If I want to match multiple spaces, I'll use " *" myself. This is more "helping" than I want or need from emacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the behavior you observe is the intended one. From the documentation of `search-whitespace-regexp`:

> If non-nil, regular expression to
>   match a sequence of whitespace chars.
>   [...] When you put a space or spaces
>   in the incremental regexp, it stands
>   for this.

Note the second sentence - whenever you put a single (or multiple) space character(s) in your regex, that gets interpreted as if you entered the value of `search-whitespace-regexp`. Since you defined that variable to be a single space character, one or multiple space character(s) in your regexp will only match a single space character in your buffer.

Probably the easiest way to achieve what you want is thus to simply set the variable to `nil`, in which case space characters are no longer treated in a special way in interactive regexp searches. A single space character in your regex will only match a single space character in the buffer.

```
(setq search-whitespace-regexp nil)
```

Comment: @Thomas: I tried exactly this, but regexp incremental search did (seemingly) the same as before. Am I missing something?

Comment: @phimuemue, I don't know - I tried it too and it works for me.

Comment: @phimuemue, However, I'm using Emacs 23.1.1, and dr. jerry writes that s/he observes the new behavior in 23.2.

Comment: @Thomas: I think I did something wrong before, now it's working... +1

Comment: @phimuemue, Very cool, glad it works for you! You aren't using GNU Emacs 23.2 by any chance?!

Comment: @Thomas thanks! Spot on, Not sure if i should file for a wiki/documentation change (see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression)

Comment: @dr jerry: Have you seen this sub-section, too? http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression#toc2 - It also lists `C-q SPC` as an alternative to setting `search-whitespace-regexp` to `nil`.

Comment: @Thomas, yeah I saw that (and changed the wiki already). C-q SPC was working, but I was using the spaces to find matching tags in a well indented html document. (copy spaces and C-M-s M-y). Thanks again for you thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `^[ ]\{5\}<` to get lines beginning with 5 spaces, followed by a `<`.